# Postman HERE API Error on Setup

Tags: gis, postman, here-api

I'm having an issue setting up to the HERE API using Postman following these two guides: [1](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geovisualization/topics/postman.html), [2](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geovisualization/topics/getting-credentials.html).

Anyways, I've loaded the Postman collection, set the global environment and placed in my app-id and app-code (Freemium account) but I still get the following error when trying to get the access token:

```
{
"msg": "app_id or app_code is wrong",
"kind": "datalens#error",
"code": 402
}
```

Does anyone have any experience with getting through this? I've tried a million different little variations but I still get the same error. Any help is vastly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Geovisualization REST API is the only API on the portal that's currently not part of the Freemium plan. I apologize for the unclear error message and will look into improving this. To gain access please contact us through the portal.